# why _joint_log_likelihood has large negative values

Tags: python, log-likelihood

How to interpret the large negative value of _joint_log_likelihood. Assume data gas only T/F class variable .

```
# Programming assignment 2
import pickle
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.naive_bayes import BernoulliNB
import numpy as np

print("Loading datasets...")
Xs = pickle.load(open('binarized_xs.pkl', 'rb'))
ys = pickle.load(open('binarized_ys.pkl', 'rb'))
print("Done Loading...")
alphaValues = list(map(lambda pow: 10 ** pow, range(-7, 8)))
print(alphaValues)
train_jll = np.zeros((10,15))
test_jll = np.zeros((10,15))

for i in range(len(Xs)):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(Xs[i], ys[i], test_size=1./3, random_state=3922) # CWID - A 20413922
    for alpha in range(len(alphaValues)):
        model = BernoulliNB(alpha=alphaValues[alpha], binarize=0.0, class_prior=None, fit_prior=True)
        sum_train = sum_test = 0
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        jll_xtrain = model._joint_log_likelihood(X_train)
        jll_xtest = model._joint_log_likelihood(X_test)
        for k in range(0, len(jll_xtrain)):
            if y_train[k] is True:
                sum_train += jll_xtrain[k][1]
            else:
                sum_train += jll_xtrain[k][0]
        for l in range(0, len(jll_xtest)):
            if y_train[l] is True:
                sum_test += jll_xtest[l][1]
            else:
                sum_test += jll_xtest[l][0]
        train_jll[i][alpha] = sum_train
        test_jll[i][alpha] = sum_test
print("Train set accuracies")
for x in range(len(train_jll)):
    print("\t".join("{0:.4f}".format(n) for n in train_jll[x]))

print("\nTest set accuracies")
for y in range(len(test_jll)):
    print("\t".join("{0:.4f}".format(n) for n in test_jll[y]))

pickle.dump((train_jll, test_jll), open('result.pkl', 'wb'))
```

Output -

Loading datasets...
Done Loading...
[1e-07, 1e-06, 1e-05, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]
Train set accuracies
-2076.9291  -1865.0913  -1653.2535  -1441.4161  -1229.5828  -1017.7904  -806.4090   -599.2828   -433.6816   -393.0386   -393.9880   -394.3349   -394.3729   -394.3767   -394.3771
-32191.9825 -32125.2076 -32058.4325 -31991.6569 -31924.8758 -31858.0396 -31790.7286 -31723.9835 -31809.0404 -34359.6845 -44846.6500 -50567.2306 -51394.1834 -51480.5729 -51489.2505
-9399.8784  -8674.5640  -7949.2493  -7223.9305  -6498.5714  -5772.8111  -5043.1794  -4285.4285  -3557.9619  -4441.6394  -7156.1042  -7949.3959  -8043.5842  -8053.1794  -8054.1407
-353033.8920    -353017.7734    -353001.6555    -352985.5397    -352969.4446    -352953.5568    -352939.8490    -352954.5902    -353374.1657    -358382.4072    -409460.4788    -733413.0483    -1191967.4850   -1306874.0175   -1320147.6708
-3180.1231  -3180.1231  -3180.1231  -3180.1227  -3180.1193  -3180.0847  -3179.7394  -3176.3400  -3147.0704  -3059.4605  -3189.5939  -3280.1913  -3292.5986  -3293.8829  -3294.0118
-4574.8093  -4574.8093  -4574.8092  -4574.8085  -4574.8016  -4574.7321  -4574.0420  -4567.5747  -4534.8631  -4827.2279  -5720.8408  -5979.6362  -6010.0678  -6013.1640  -6013.4741
-12062.2160 -11525.7137 -10989.2111 -10452.7065 -9916.1810  -9379.4479  -8840.6448  -8281.8848  -7575.0972  -6582.4242  -6736.2181  -7272.9840  -7364.0583  -7373.7458  -7374.7206
-5259.2360  -5259.2360  -5259.2360  -5259.2361  -5259.2374  -5259.2503  -5259.3793  -5260.7374  -5279.3215  -5554.7885  -6477.3544  -6868.2764  -6919.7250  -6925.0321  -6925.5645
-3514.5228  -3489.1943  -3463.8658  -3438.5362  -3413.1960  -3387.7507  -3361.3059  -3328.3483  -3321.7284  -4067.7458  -5939.6312  -6559.4446  -6635.7135  -6643.5165  -6644.2986
-16439.2193 -16439.2192 -16439.2186 -16439.2126 -16439.1520 -16438.5472 -16432.5838 -16380.1945 -16158.3379 -16977.7163 -21690.7497 -23938.6506 -24244.2920 -24275.9518 -24279.1292

Test set accuracies
-1053.7924  -945.5709   -837.3494   -729.1282   -620.9093   -512.7138   -404.7524   -299.1838   -215.8272   -196.2691   -196.9655   -197.1646   -197.1862   -197.1883   -197.1886
-15989.8827 -15957.6465 -15925.4103 -15893.1734 -15860.9307 -15828.6299 -15795.8012 -15761.3437 -15802.3473 -17104.9942 -22402.1020 -25280.9583 -25696.8189 -25740.2591 -25744.6225
-4534.7085  -4177.8078  -3820.9070  -3464.0050  -3107.0909  -2750.0567  -2391.8688  -2025.7431  -1695.5868  -2189.5685  -3580.8558  -3984.4531  -4032.3297  -4037.2065  -4037.6951
-177068.0250    -177042.6961    -177017.3678    -176992.0408    -176966.7274    -176941.5493    -176917.7628    -176910.2919    -177109.2109    -179594.7458    -205083.1285    -366890.6006    -596016.9983    -653440.6438    -660074.2024
-1620.5941  -1620.5941  -1620.5940  -1620.5938  -1620.5919  -1620.5727  -1620.3805  -1618.4869  -1602.0804  -1548.8017  -1601.9069  -1644.1081  -1649.9448  -1650.5496  -1650.6103
-2300.3443  -2300.3443  -2300.3443  -2300.3440  -2300.3405  -2300.3063  -2299.9661  -2296.7773  -2280.6516  -2426.8969  -2874.4986  -3004.2282  -3019.4848  -3021.0371  -3021.1926
-6679.6097  -6357.2478  -6034.8857  -5712.5225  -5390.1476  -5067.6560  -4744.0017  -4409.1390  -3991.1972  -3405.6240  -3400.4154  -3643.0063  -3685.1813  -3689.6778  -3690.1304
-2566.8863  -2566.8863  -2566.8863  -2566.8864  -2566.8872  -2566.8959  -2566.9826  -2567.8859  -2579.5423  -2735.3703  -3228.0735  -3432.8776  -3459.7340  -3462.5032  -3462.7809
-1767.5406  -1758.3303  -1749.1199  -1739.9090  -1730.6931  -1721.4272  -1711.6835  -1698.6756  -1696.0342  -2056.3261  -2977.0952  -3283.5231  -3321.2606  -3325.1219  -3325.5089
-8463.1185  -8460.8158  -8458.5130  -8456.2073  -8453.8744  -8451.2691  -8445.9788  -8417.2311  -8295.8823  -8635.8290  -10888.2128 -11982.1214 -12131.2829 -12146.7387 -12148.2898

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common to get a very large -ve value for joint log likely hood (let's say value you got is -x ). You divide that by the number of observation in your dataset (Say there are n rows in your dataset). Then avg probability of each observation is `e^(-x/n)`

Answer (score 0):

It's a stats question but large negative values of log-odds mean that it is unlikely.

https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/other/mult-pkg/faq/general/faq-how-do-i-interpret-odds-ratios-in-logistic-regression/